# Hyperparameter tuning on the whole dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, hyperparameters

It may be a weird question because I don't fully understand hyperparameter-tuning yet.

Currently I'm using `gridSearchCV` of `sklearn` to tune the parameters of a `randomForestClassifier` like this:

```
gs = GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42), param_grid={'max_depth': range(5, 25, 4), 'min_samples_leaf': range(5, 40, 5),'criterion': ['entropy', 'gini']}, scoring=scoring, cv=3, refit='Accuracy', n_jobs=-1)
gs.fit(X_Distances, Y)
results = gs.cv_results_
```

After that I check the `gs` object for the `best_params` and `best_score`. Now I'm using `best_params` to instantiate a `RandomForestClassifier` and use stratified validation again to record metrics and print a confusion matrix:

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000, min_samples_leaf=7, max_depth=18, criterion='entropy', random_state=42)
accuracy = []
metrics = {'accuracy':[], 'precision':[], 'recall':[], 'fscore':[], 'support':[]}
counter = 0

print('################################################### RandomForest ###################################################')
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X_Distances,Y):
    X_train, X_test = X_Distances[train_index], X_Distances[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = Y[train_index], Y[test_index]
    rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = rf.predict(X_test)

    precision, recall, fscore, support = np.round(score(y_test, y_pred), 2)
    metrics['accuracy'].append(round(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred), 2))
    metrics['precision'].append(precision)
    metrics['recall'].append(recall)
    metrics['fscore'].append(fscore)
    metrics['support'].append(support)

    print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
    matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
    methods.saveConfusionMatrix(matrix, ('confusion_matrix_randomforest_distances_' + str(counter) +'.png'))
    counter = counter+1

meanAcc= round(np.mean(np.asarray(metrics['accuracy'])),2)*100
print('meanAcc: ', meanAcc)
```

Is this a reasonable approach or do I have something completely wrong?

EDIT:

I just tested the following:

```
gs = GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42), param_grid={'max_depth': range(5, 25, 4), 'min_samples_leaf': range(5, 40, 5),'criterion': ['entropy', 'gini']}, scoring=scoring, cv=3, refit='Accuracy', n_jobs=-1)
gs.fit(X_Distances, Y)
```

This yields `best_score = 0.5362903225806451` at `best_index = 28`. When I check the accuracies in the 3 folds at index 28 I get:

1. split0: 0.5185929648241207
2. split1: 0.526686807653575
3. split2: 0.5637651821862348

Which leads to the mean test accuracy: 0.5362903225806451. best_params: `{'criterion': 'entropy', 'max_depth': 21, 'min_samples_leaf': 5}`

Now I run this code which is using the mentioned best_params with a stratified 3 fold split (like GridSearchCV):

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, min_samples_leaf=5, max_depth=21, criterion='entropy', random_state=42)
accuracy = []
metrics = {'accuracy':[], 'precision':[], 'recall':[], 'fscore':[], 'support':[]}
counter = 0
print('################################################### RandomForest_Gini ###################################################')
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X_Distances,Y):
    X_train, X_test = X_Distances[train_index], X_Distances[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = Y[train_index], Y[test_index]
    rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = rf.predict(X_test)

    precision, recall, fscore, support = np.round(score(y_test, y_pred))
    metrics['accuracy'].append(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
    metrics['precision'].append(precision)
    metrics['recall'].append(recall)
    metrics['fscore'].append(fscore)
    metrics['support'].append(support)

    print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
    matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
    methods.saveConfusionMatrix(matrix, ('confusion_matrix_randomforest_distances_' + str(counter) +'.png'))
    counter = counter+1

meanAcc= np.mean(np.asarray(metrics['accuracy']))
print('meanAcc: ', meanAcc)
```

The metrics dictionairy yields the exact same accuracies (split0: 0.5185929648241207, split1: 0.526686807653575, split2: 0.5637651821862348)

However the mean calculation is a bit off: 0.5363483182213101

Answer (score 3):

While this seems like a promising approach, you are taking a risk:
*You are tuning, and then evaluating the results of this tuning using the same dataset.*

While in some cases this is a legit approach, I would carefully check the difference between the metric you get at the end, and the reported `best_score`. If these are far off, you should tune your model only on the training set (you are now tuning using everything). In practice, this means performing the split beforehand and making sure that `GridSearchCV` does not see the test set.

This could be done like this:

```
train_x, train_y, val_x, val_y = train_test_split(X_distances, Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
```

You would then run tuning and training on the `train_x, train_y`.

On the other hand, if the two scores are close, I guess you are good to go.

Comment: The scores are very close. Your suggestion would mean that if I want to validate using cross validation I would run `GridSearchCV` three times (1/fold)?

Comment: I made a code example (unfortunately not tested). In general this is not needed since your validation score is close to the `best_score` but still you can keep it in mind for when it won't :)

Comment: Ok thanks! Unfortunately I still don't understand why it is a problem to begin with. GridSearchCV creates models and tests them using cross validation (train/test data split). In the end I have a parameter set which I use to define and train a new model which is validated again with cross validation.

Comment: Imagine you are tuning manually. You try a set of parameters and get a score (on another dataset because as you correctly stated `GridSearchCV` will do that). Then you try reducing the learning rate and you get a better score. So now you decide to keep this `learning rate`. Now imagine you do that many many times. Now your dataset has not **directly** seen the test dataset, but **you** did, and you made design decisions based on that! Which means that your model has actually *seen the test data through the eyes of its programmer*.

Comment: I updated my initial post with an illustrating example. In the end I want to replicate the predictions the best_estimator found with gridSearchCV made. To do so I perform stratified cross validation (same options as gridSearch) on a classifier with best_params. So I'm able to reproducde the predictions of the best estimator for the confusion_matrix.